# How to get icons for entities from eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am writing an eclipse plugin. How do I get the various images from eclipse library? So I don't have have keep a local set of images for the standard entities, e.g classes, interfaces, junits, etc.

**EDIT :** I used `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().getImage(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJ_FILE)` from the article : http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Using%20Images%20In%20Eclipse/Using%20Images%20In%20Eclipse.html.
That did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct (AFAIK), but not all Shared Images are available like that. I suggest experimenting with various constants (e.g. IMG_ELCL_REMOVEALL works in a project of mine).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this method:

```
public Image getImage() {
    ImageDescriptor descriptor =
        Activator.getImageDescriptor("$nl$/icons/xxx.png");
    return descriptor.createImage();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Image browser view. See [here](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Fviews%2Fimage_browser_view.htm) Refer [this post](http://lmap.blogspot.co.at/2008/03/platform-scheme-uri.html) for using eclipse standard images/icons in your plugin