# Where can I find eclipse icons?

Tags: eclipse, icons

I search for a library, a ".zip"-archiv or another easy way to get all "eclipse-icons". I mean the icons on the top of the tabs (Error, Debug, Search, Task and so on..)

Any idea?

Comment: The icons are in the various jars for the Eclipse plugins which own the icons.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get icons for entities from eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562850/how-to-get-icons-for-entities-from-eclipse)

Answer (score 6):

Eclipse actually has a special view that shows all available icons:

**Window ▸ Show View ▸ Other... ▸ Plug-in Development ▸ Plug-in Image Browser**

[image: Plug-in Image Browser]

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to find the plugin they are in, or download similar ones? Try http://eclipse-icons.i24.cc/

Comment: Sadly, this super useful web site appears to be no longer online.

Answer (score 0):

I found it was much easier to just write a little program to extract the images. The code below pulls out all *.png from the JAR files in the Eclipse plugins directory.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

public class ExtractEclipseIcons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dir="C:\\eclipse\\e47dtp\\eclipse\\plugins";

        for (File file : new File(dir).listFiles()) {
            if(file.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
                unpackImagesFromJAR(file);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void unpackImagesFromJAR(File file) {
        try (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(file)){
            for (ZipEntry ze : Collections.list(zip.entries())) {
                String name = ze.getName();
                if(name.endsWith(".png")) {
                    try(InputStream in = zip.getInputStream(ze)){
                        String outname = file.getName()+"/"+name;
                        File outfile = new File("data/"+outname.replace('/', '_').replace('\\', '_'));
                        stream2File(in,outfile);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void stream2File(InputStream is, File file) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
        try {
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
            try {
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            } finally {
                output.close();
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this tool: http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/

It allows you to extract/cange nearly any icon/pic inside an exe file.